# How can i rescale every column in my data frame to a 0-100 scale? (in r)

Tags: r, scaling

i am trying to get all the colums of my data frame to be in the same scale..

right now i have something like this... where a is on a 0-1 scale  b is on a 100 scale and c is on a 1-5 scale

```
a   b     c 
0   89   4 
1   93   3 
0   88   5
```

How would i get it to a 100scale like this...

```
a     b      c 
0     89     80 
100   93     60 
0     88     100
```

i hope that is somewhat clear..
i have tried scale() but can not seem to get it to work.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15468866/scaling-a-numeric-matrix-in-r-with-values-0-to-1

Comment: Your `b` column doesn't seem to be scaled in the example... but I assume that one also should be.

Comment: my b column is already on a 100pt scale, i dont want it to change.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Using `scale`, if `dat` is the name of your data frame:

```
## for one column
dat$a <- scale(dat$a, center = FALSE, scale = max(dat$a, na.rm = TRUE)/100)
## for every column of your data frame
dat <- data.frame(lapply(dat, function(x) scale(x, center = FALSE, scale = max(x, na.rm = TRUE)/100)))
```

For a simple case like this, you could also write your own function.

```
fn <- function(x) x * 100/max(x, na.rm = TRUE)
fn(c(0,1,0))
# [1]   0 100   0
## to one column
dat$a <- fn(dat$a)
## to all columns of your data frame
dat <- data.frame(lapply(dat, fn))
```

Comment: This seems to work but is returning NA for all my 0-1 scale columns

Comment: Possibly adding `na.rm = TRUE` to `max` would help. Though I can't tell for sure without looking at your data.

Answer (score 5):

My experience is that this is still unanswered, what if one of the columns had a -2, the current answer would not produce a 0-100 scale. While I appreciate the answer, when I attempted it, I have variables that are -100 to 100 and this left some negative still?

I have a solution in case this applies to you:

```
rescale <- function(x) (x-min(x))/(max(x) - min(x)) * 100
dat <- rescale(dat)
```

Answer (score 0):

Even more simple and flexible to other scales is the `rescale()` function from the scales package. If you wanted to scale from 3 to 50 for some reason, you could set the `to` parameter to `c(3,50)` instead of `c(0,100)` here. Additionally, you can set the `from` parameter if your data needs to fit to the scale of another dataset (i.e. the min/max of your data should not equal the min/max of the scale you want to set). Here I've provided an example where 0 would be the midpoint between -100 to 100, so rescaling to 0:100 would now place 0 at 50 (the halfway point).

```
# 0 to 100 scaling
rescale(1:10, to = c(0,100))
# [1]   0.00000  11.11111  22.22222  33.33333  44.44444  55.55556  66.66667  77.77778  88.88889
# [10] 100.00000

# use 'from' to indicate the extended range of values
rescale(seq(0,100,10), to = c(0,100), from = c(-100,100))
# [1]  50  55  60  65  70  75  80  85  90  95 100
```