# is it necessary to center and scale data before predicting?

Tags: r, r-caret

In the train function of the caret package it is possible to perform centering and scaling of predictors as in the following example:

```
knnFit <- train(Direction ~ ., data = training, method = "knn",
                preProcess = c("center","scale"))
```

Setting this transformation in train should give a better evaluation of the performance of the algorithm during resampling.

In this case when I use the model to predict the response for new data should I care about centering and scaling or this operation is included in the final model?

Is the following operation sufficient?

```
pred <- predict(knnFit, newdata = test)
```

Thanks!

Comment: No, previously you should center and scaling. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15468866/scaling-a-numeric-matrix-in-r-with-values-0-to-1 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15215457/standardize-data-columns-in-r

Answer (score 11, accepted):

preProces specified in the train object will be applied to the new data without preprocessing the new data first. So your operation is sufficient.

Also have a look at the extract from the caret website below. There is also a whole section purely about preprocessing. Definitely worth your time reading through it.

You can find the [caret website](http://topepo.github.io/caret/index.html) here.

> These processing steps would be applied during any predictions
>   generated using predict.train, extractPrediction or extractProbs (see
>   details later in this document). The pre-processing would not be
>   applied to predictions that directly use the object$finalModel object.