# How do I normalize the Y-axis of histogram between 0 and 1?

Tags: r, histogram

I need to normalized the Y-axis of an histogram between 0-1.

This is a part of my data.frame:

```
1.8064 2.2016 2.4506 2.1828 2.1171 1.9308 2.1707 2.1885
2.2310 2.2400 1.9115 2.1527 2.0934 1.7989 2.2144 2.0091
1.9248 2.2038 1.9676 1.9224 1.9502 1.7990 2.0824 2.1300
2.0095 2.0341 1.8433 1.8361 1.9958 1.8243 2.0397 2.0482
2.1143 2.2627 1.7620 1.7561 1.9490 1.9803 1.9336 2.2511
2.2377 2.5414 1.7867 1.6618 2.5090 1.8325 2.0212 2.1616
2.3476 2.1878 2.0469 1.7508 2.2969 1.7939 2.0291 2.0721
2.3534 2.0932 2.3502 1.9960 2.0710 1.9923 1.7787 1.9772
2.2607 2.1504 2.3685 2.1148 2.1961 1.7738 1.8405 2.0135
2.2411 1.9916 2.4726 2.0347 2.0751 1.7570 1.8874 1.9385
2.1913 1.8981 2.2441 2.3068 2.1198 2.1484 1.8056 1.7747
2.0842 1.8750 2.3023 2.1204 1.8972 2.1534 1.8028 1.9401
2.2105 1.9618 2.2472 1.9656 2.3098 1.9771 1.9520 1.8627
2.2863 1.9959 2.1781 1.9544 1.9281 1.9286 1.9699 2.0330
2.1987 2.0583 2.0953 2.0206 2.1148 2.3789 1.7052 1.9145
2.0513 2.0850 1.9810 2.4943 1.9120 2.2209 1.9461 2.0882
2.0049 2.0416 1.9303 2.3681 1.8974 2.0054 1.9261 1.9097
1.6882 2.1196 1.8641 2.3600 2.0931 1.7641 2.1131 1.7748
1.8840 1.7604 1.7664 2.2000 2.0055 1.8229 1.9871 1.9168
1.7340 1.9656 1.8480 2.0523 1.9950 1.8716 1.9206 1.7786
```

And this is what I'm doing currently:

```
for (i in data){
  x <- i

  h<-hist(x, plot = FALSE)
  h$density = h$counts/sum(h$counts)

  plot(h, col="red", xlim = c(0,max(data)))}
```

But I get this picture:

[image]

But what I really want is something like this (Y axis between 0-1):

[image]

Comment: Use scale() function (http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/base/scale)

Comment: @algui91 scale where?. I don't want to scale my dataframe, I want to scale the frequency.  Is there any way to do this? I'm a bit of a newbie in R

Comment: Check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15215457/standardize-data-columns-in-r

Comment: @algui91 Thank you. I checked but my doubt has not been resolved.

Comment: If I am not wrong, `scale`, althought its name, does a normalization between [-1,1] of the data. It gives you a normal distribution of mean 0 and sd = 1. Is not that what you want?

Comment: @algui91 Yes, but I don't want to scale my X-axis, I want to scale my Y-axis between 0-1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To scale your Y between `[0,1]` you could use what [flodel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1201032/flodel) suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15468970/1612432)

```
maxs <- apply(a, 2, max)
mins <- apply(a, 2, min)
scale(a, center = mins, scale = maxs - mins)
```

But modifying that code to use only your `y` column:

```
maxs <- max(y)
mins <- min(y)
scale(y, center = mins, scale = maxs - mins)
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Just divide each observation by the max to normalize the data to 1.

But the question remains, why? If the y-axis is normalized 0-1, it implies probability, which this clearly is not.